# Why a segment of length $\sqrt{2}$ can be drawn but a segment of length $\pi$ cannot?

Tags: geometry, irrational-numbers, geometric-construction

We know that both $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are irrational. Also, it has been proved that a segment of length $\pi$ can not be drawn whereas a segment of length $\sqrt{2}$ can be drawn. Why is it so, though both are irrational?

Comment: Why would rationality be related the possibility of drawing its length? See the concept of [constructible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number).

Comment: On the other hand, with a circle, I can draw an arc of length $\pi$, but not an arc of length $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: You can draw an arc of a circle of length $\pi$ with compass and straightedge, given a line segment of unit length and in a finite number of steps. You can't draw a line segment of length $\pi$. Read more [about constructible numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number).

Answer (score 3):

If you define "drawing" a number as being able to construct it with ruler and compass, $\sqrt{2}$ can be drawn, while $\pi$ can't. But $\sqrt[3]{2}$ can't be drawn either. In fact, in some sense the overwhelming majority of numbers can't be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

root(2) is the length of the diagonal of a square which which side is 1.
root(2) is algebraic it is the root of $x^2-2$ and

$\pi$ is not algebraic, it is transcendantal, remark that $\pi$ is the perimeter of a circle of radius 1/2